# ada - declarations must come before begin?

Tags: ada

Question:  why and how to fix this error message about ADA? Thax

12:04 declarations must come before "begin"
29:01 statement expected

```
With Ada.Text_IO; Use Ada.Text_IO;
With Ada.Integer_Text_IO; Use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
With Ada.Strings.Unbounded; Use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
With Ada.Strings.Bounded;

procedure polynomial is

begin

   function evaluate (x: Integer) return Integer is

     type i is  new Integer;
     type p is  new Integer;
     type x is  new Integer;

    begin

      for i in reverse 0..10 loop
         i:= i-1;
         p:= coef(i)+x*p;

      end loop;

      return p;

   end evaluate;
end polynomial;
```

Comment: As someone else said on 6 March, "go find a book or tutorial on Ada and study it. Your understanding of Ada syntax is so poor right now that there's not much we can do to help you in a StackOverflow question.” You could start [here](http://www.adaic.org/learn/materials/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster doesn’t appear to have studied any language references or tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, declarations must come before `begin`.  Thus, if you have a declaration, it must come before the `begin` of the construct that encloses it.  For example, the type declarations of `i`, `x`, and `p` (which should not be type declarations, but that's another problem) are directly enclosed in the `evaluate` function.  Therefore, they must appear before the `begin` of the `evaluate` function, as they are.

The thing is that this applies to `function` and `procedure` declarations, too--and a complete function body, such as `evaluate`, counts as a declaration for this rule.  `evaluate` is directly enclosed in `polynomial`.  Therefore, it must appear before the `begin` line belonging to `polynomial`, whereas your code puts it right after the `begin` line, which is illegal.

There are actually two ways to fix it: (1) Move `evaluate` before the `begin` line.  (2) Add a block that begins with `declare`:

```
procedure polynomial is
begin
   declare
     function evaluate (x: Integer) return Integer is
        i : Integer;
        -- etc.
     begin
        -- etc.
     end evaluate;
   begin  -- this is the BEGIN line of the block
     -- Now put some code here!
   end;  -- this is the end of the block
end polynomial;
```

Now the `evaluate` function is directly enclosed in the block, not in `polynomial`, and it must occur before the `begin` line of the block, but it doesn't have to occur before the `begin` line of `polynomial`.

A couple other things:  This declaration:

```
type i is new Integer;
```

does **not** mean that "the type of `i` is an integer".  It means you're declaring a new **type** named `i`.  You don't want that, you want a variable.

```
i : Integer;
```

Second: note the part of the block where I said "now put some code here".  That's necessary.  Declaring the function `evaluate` does not run the function.  You have to put in a statement that calls it, if you ever want your function to run.  Your original incorrect code didn't have any statements that called `evaluate`, which is why I am not sure whether you understood that concept.

Comment: Making some modification in the code then the next message appears: gcc -c polynomial.adb
polynomial.adb:35:03: statement expected
gnatmake: "polynomial.adb" compilation error

Comment: Obviously you didn't obey the comment that said "now put some code here!" -- even a "null;" statement would do.

Comment: @Tania Shark8 might be right.  However, when you say "you made **some** modification", and then you got a compilation error, without telling us what the error is, you cannot expect anyone to help you.  We don't know what the code is, and we don't know what the error is.  We do not have ESP.

Comment: May i send you an email? Asking specific questions because this thing is blocking me....

Comment: I don't really have time to be a personal tutor.  And it appears to me that you haven't yet learned the basics of programming in Ada and are trying to get things done by guessing, and if you sent me an e-mail, I'd have to spend a lot of time tutoring you on the basics.  I think you need to find a book or tutorial on Ada for beginners, and when they show you examples, type them in yourself and compile them to help you get an understanding of what Ada programs look like.  After you've spent some time on this, then if you run into a problem that you can't solve, then post a question here.

Comment: Ok, thank you, in fact i know Ada, but the specific question is about this message: main.adb:37:08 subtype mark required in this context. main.adb:37:08 found "polynomial" declared at fun.ads:4  gnatmake: "main.adb" compilation error.

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but if you think `type i is new integer` is the way to declare a variable, you do not know Ada.  And since you've made modifications to your code, how are we supposed to know what code the compiler is giving you error messages about?